# How to get Access Token with JavaScript API dynamically

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to publish an action for the Facebook Grahp in order to get my App approval..
Error:

Publish Actions
You must publish at least one action to your Timeline using this action type.

So I created a simple page to publish the action (I got the code form: Graph API) and it's this one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="de-DE" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 

<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fashion_econtest: http://ogp.me/ns/apps/fashion_econtest#">

    <title>Fashion</title>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="MyAppId" /> 
    <meta property="og:type" content="fashion:contest" /> 
    <meta property="og:title" content="eContest" /> 
    <meta property="og:image" content="The Image" /> 
    <meta property="og:description" content="Registrati e vinci cli accessori più fashion dell&#039;anno!" /> 
    <meta property="og:url" content="MyURL">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function postSubscribe(){
            FB.api(
            '/me/fashion:subscribe',
            'post',
            {share:'MyUrl'},
            function(response){
                if(!response){
                    alert('Error');
                }else if(response.error) {
                    alert(response.error.message);
                }else{
                    alert('Subscribe was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'MyAppId', // App ID
                status     : true, // check login status
                cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });
        };

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js";
            d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
        }(document));
    </script>

    <h3>Fashion</h3>
    <p>
        <img title="Vinci i premi più Fashion!" src="http://xxxxxx.de/img/yyyyyy.jpg" width="550"/>
    </p>

    <br>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Subscribe" onclick="postSubscribe();" />
    </form>
</body>
```

But once I send the Request, I get the follwonig Error:

> An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

How can I get the Access Token with Java Script FB-API dynamically and make this working?

Many Thanks for your help!!
Amin

Answer (score 1):

Facebook exchanges access_tokens automatically based on your application Id. I think you are looking for getting the currently active access_token using FB API methods.
Try FB.getLoginStatus API call. For more details see...
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Answer (score 0):

Call FB.login first, and ask for the appropriate permission (publish_actions).

(Or just do the whole things using the Graph API explorer instead of writing a script for something you’ll only need once.)